# Cannot ask questions on SO because tags disappear on submit

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, user-interface

I tried to ask a question today on Stack Overflow. The site told me that I did not include any tags, but I did. I used the tags [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [jscrollpane](/questions/tagged/jscrollpane).

I saw them there, then clicked the button. They vanished and the site said I did not add tags. I tried this in multiple browsers, all of which gave the same result.

On Mac OS X, I used Firefox 3.6.20, Safari and Chrome; on Linux, I used Chrome and Firefox; and on Windows I used IE8.

The interface I see here on Meta — the window with potential tags appearing as I type — does not show up on the primary site at the moment, so I can ask questions here but not there.

Comment: unable to reproduce.

Comment: Seems that this affects only "new" unlogged users. Try to log in and then ask your question.

Comment: We're looking into this...

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix. I guess I should have pointed out that I hit the issue when I was posting a question as an anon user. I only registered an account because you can't post a question on meta. without one and I figured it was worth the effort to submit a bug report, but I think you might want to rethink that policy if this is where you want people to submit bug reports.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out removing code from anonymous users means they don't have access to it.  Who'd have thunk it?

Fix deployed.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a very similer issue, but it seems to be fixed now.  here's the error I was getting:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8)  Timestamp:
>   Fri, 16 Sep 2011 18:36:37 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method  Line: 1 
>   Char: 2351  Code: 0  URI: cdn.sstatic.net/js/…

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I spent over an hour trying to ask a question. This drives me mad.
My tags were [flex](/questions/tagged/flex), [as3](/questions/tagged/as3) and [xml](/questions/tagged/xml).

I got the same result with Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera on OS X and Firefox and IE8 on Windows.